# I wants to integrate Excel with Protractor with VCode with Gerkin language

Tags: excel, visual-studio-code, protractor, feature-file

I want to integrate Excel with Protractor with VCode with Gerkin language.can any one help me out with the same ?

Comment: Is this on Microsoft Office 365? I'm confused with this question.

Comment: This question is way too vague. Mention what approaches you have tried and what issues you encountered

Comment: I have Protractor with Cucumber BDD framework, which is in VS code, I use to give data from the Example like this , But now I want it from Excel Sheet-Something Like This ----- Scenario Outline:Ability to Select Filter on Edit page
        And User switch to Filter Screen
        And Select all Metric
        And User selects CareerTrack filter by selecting <CareerTrack>
        And User performs Apply
        And User switch to CollapseFilter Screen
        And User collapse scenario details
        Examples:
            | CareerTrack     |
            | Client & Market |